# Apache Airflow - Was Working Fine Now Says Log File Isn't Local Error & Exceptions are Popping Up

Tags: airflow

So it looks like my install of apache airflow on a Google Compute Engine instance broke down. Everything was working great and then two days ago all the DAG runs show up stuck in a running state. I am using LocalExecutioner.

When I try to look at the log I get this error:

*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/collector/aa_main_combined_collector/2017-12-15T09:00:00
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

I didn't touch a setting anywhere. I looked through all the config files and I scanned the logs and I see this error

[2017-12-16 20:08:42,558] {jobs.py:355} DagFileProcessor0 ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 347, in helper
    pickle_dags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1584, in process_file
    self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1173, in _process_dags
    dag_run = self.create_dag_run(dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 763, in create_dag_run
    last_scheduled_run = qry.scalar()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2843, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2814, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2784, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2855, in **iter**
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2878, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 69, in sigint_handler
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0

Any thoughts out there?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem though in doing so I discovered another problem.

Long and short of it as soon as I manually started the scheduler, everything worked again. It appears the problem was that the scheduler did not get restarted correctly after a system reboot.

I have scheduler running through SystemD. The Webserver .service works fine. However I do notice that the scheduler .service continually restarts. It appears there is an issue there I need to resolve. This part of it is solved for now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the log URL, verify if it ends with a date with special characters +:

> &execution_date=2018-02-23T08:00:00+00:00

This was fixed [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2982).

You can replace the `+` for `-`, or replace all special characters, in my case:

> &execution_date=2018-02-23T08%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00

This happens [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/a0deb506c070637abc3c426bc7d060e3fe6c854d/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py#L97).

The FileTaskHandler can not load the log from local disk, and try to load  from worker.

Another thing that could be causing this error is the exclusion of the airflow/logs folder or the sub folders inside it.